# Find sufficient condition over the coefficients of a quartic polynomial to have only positive roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

For a stability question I'm looking for conditions under the coefficients $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ of a monic quartic polynomial $$f(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$ that guarantee that all the roots of this polynomial are positive. Also, I need to find sufficient conditions under the coefficients that guarantee at least one positive root (like $d<0$), or conditions that guarantee that there isn't any positive root. I'm aware of approaches like the one of the following article: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266543070_Absence_of_positive_roots_of_complex_cubic_and_quartic_polynomials, but I need simpler relations between the coefficients, since my polynomial of interest has coefficients in terms of a lot of variables. Thank you in advance for your comments.

Comment: This text by Michel Coste, An Introduction to Semialgebraic Geometry, which you can find here https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/Enseignement.html  is very well written, and could be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you @orangeskid, I will take a look on it. Maybe the Sturm sequence will be useful, or the Sylvester matrix can be applied in this case. I hope that the expressions don't get very messy.

Comment: You are very welcome.  The number of real roots is determined by the signature and rank of the matrix $V\cdot V^t$, there $V$ is the Vandermonde formed with the roots.  It's entries are sums of powers of roots, so expressable in terms of coefficients. This is the Hermite matrix I think.

Answer (score 1):

More than a comment:

The necessary and sufficient conditions that a polynomial has all the roots real is that the Hermite matrix
$$(p_{i+j})_{0\le i,j \le n-1}$$
is positive semi-definite, where
$$p_i = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^i$$
are the power sums of the roots of the equation. Thus we get a condition on the coefficients of the equation, using [Newton-Girard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_power_sums_in_terms_of_elementary_symmetric_polynomials) identities.

This is rather cumbersome.

Let's consider the case of a polynomial $P$ of degree $4$. We are looking for conditions that the polynomial has all roots real. A necessary condition is that $P'$ has all roots real. But we know that this is equivalent to its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) $\operatorname{Disc} P'$ being $\ge 0$.

Assume that the roots $t_i$ of $P'$ are real and distinct ($ \operatorname{Disc} P'> 0$). Now, $P$ will have all roots real if two of the number $P(t_i)$ are negative and one positive.  A necessary condition for this is $\prod P(t_i) > 0$. This product equals the resultant of $P$ and $P'$ ( up to a positive constant), or, the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_4) of $P$, $\operatorname{Disc}P$.

Let's sum up: the condition
$\operatorname{Disc} P, \operatorname{Disc} P'> 0$ is equivalent to the roots $t_i$ of $P'$ are real and distinct and $\prod P(t_i) > 0$. We have $2$ negatives among the $P(t_i)$  if and only if : at least one of the inequalities
$$P(t_1)+ P(t_2) + P(t_3)<0\\
P(t_1) P(t_2) + P(t_1)P(t_3)+ P(t_2) P(t_3)<0$$
is satisfied.

Let $P(x) = x^4 + a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d$, $t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$ the roots of $P'(x)$. Then $P(t_i)$, $i=1,3$ are the roots of the equation
(obtained with [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%20%7Bc%20%2B%202%20b%20x%20%2B%203%20a%20x%5E2%20%2B%204%20x%5E3%2C%20y%20-%20%28x%5E4%2B%20a%20x%5E3%20%2B%20b%20x%5E2%20%2B%20c%20x%20%2B%20d%29%7D%2C%20%7By%2Ca%2Cb%2Cc%2Cd%7D%2C%20%7Bx%7D%5D))
$$-a^2 b^2 c^2 + 4 b^3 c^2 + 4 a^3 c^3 - 18 a b c^3 + 27 c^4 + 4 a^2 b^3 d - 16 b^4 d - 18 a^3 b c d + 80 a b^2 c d + 6 a^2 c^2 d - 144 b c^2 d + 27 a^4 d^2 - 144 a^2 b d^2 + 128 b^2 d^2 + 192 a c d^2 - 256 d^3+\\ 
+(- 4 a^2 b^3  + 16 b^4  + 18 a^3 b c  - 80 a b^2 c  - 6 a^2 c^2  + 144 b c^2  - 54 a^4 d  + \\+ 288 a^2 b d  - 256 b^2 d  - 384 a c d  + 768 d^2 )y +\\
 + (27 a^4  - 144 a^2 b  + 128 b^2  + 192 a c  - 768 d )y^2 + 256 y^3=0$$

Now, the free term of this equation is $- \operatorname{Disc} P$, and this must be negative, like we mentioned above. Now, if either
$$-(27 a^4  - 144 a^2 b  + 128 b^2  + 192 a c  - 768 d )<0$$
or
$$(- 4 a^2 b^3  + 16 b^4  + 18 a^3 b c  - 80 a b^2 c  - 6 a^2 c^2  + 144 b c^2  - 54 a^4 d  + \\+ 288 a^2 b d  - 256 b^2 d  - 384 a c d  + 768 d^2 )<0$$

( coupled with $\operatorname{Disc} P , \operatorname{Disc} P>0$), then all of the roots of $P$ are real. If we also want them positive, then we need also $a<0$, $b>0$, $c<0$, $d>0$.

Comment: Nice approach! It's definitively easier to find cubic roots, and in my particular case the most complex coefficient is the constant one, so this way looks very promising.

Comment: @Julián: Glad if it's of any use. Note that I added the explicit expressions that would ensure real roots. For instance, if the discriminants of both $P$, $P'$ are $>0$, and $27 a^4  - 144 a^2 b  + 128 b^2  + 192 a c  - 768 d >0$ then all roots are real. (the other expression is just more complicated...)